# Como enviar dados em javascript para o mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tendo só uma pequena dificuldade , pois os dados estão indo só que pra mesma tabela ,tipo e uma parte está duplicada .

Bem tá todo os código a query, o form e o javascript .

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}


if($_POST)
{  
    $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
    $pedido_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_refeicao']);
    $num_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['num_refeicao']);
    $pedido_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_bebida']);
    $num_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['num_bebida']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO mpedido(numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida) VALUES('$numero_mesa','$pedido_refeicao','$num_refeicao','$pedido_bebida','$num_bebida')";
        $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Peixaria</title>
    <style>
        .add {
            text - decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.add,add2{ text-decoration:none;}
#selecionados input,#selecionados2 input{ margin:10px;}
</style>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
        <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
    <main>
        <form method="post" action="pedidos.php">
            <header>
                <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
            </header>
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <span>Mesa</span>
                    <input type="text"id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>

                </label>
                <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
                <div class="pedidos">

                    <select name="pedido_refeicao[]" id="pedido_refeicao"class="selecionar" readonly>
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                        <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
                        <option  >Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
                        <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
                        <option >Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
                        <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
                        <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
                        <option >Sardinha Frita</option>
                        <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
                        <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
                        <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
                        <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>
                </div>
               <br>
                <div  class="pedidos">

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <select name="pedido_bebida[]" id="pedido_bebida"class="selecionar">
                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola 1l</option>
                        <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
                        <option >Bare 2l</option> 
                        <option >Fanta Uva</option>
                        <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
                        <option >Sprit</option> 
                        <option >Cola Cola </option>
                        <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
                        <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
                        <option >Guaraná Baré</option>
                        <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
                        <option >Suco Manga</option>
                        <option >Suco Pessego</option>
                        <option >Suco Uva</option> 
                        <option >Suco Maracujá</option>
                        <option >Suco Laranja</option>
                        <option >Suco Caju</option> 
                        <option >Agua Mineral </option>
                        <option >Agua com Gas </option>
                        <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
                        <option >Limonada Natural</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                    <hr>
                    Selecionados
                    <hr>
                    <div class="selecionados">

                    </div>

                </div>
<br>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Fazer Pedido</button>   
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(".add").on('click',function(){ 
            var cont=0;
            var holder = $(this).closest('.pedidos');
            holder.find(".selecionados input").each(function(){
                if($(this).val()==holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html()){
                    cont++;
                }
            });
            if(cont>0) { 
                alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");
            } else{
                holder.find(".selecionados").append(
                    "<input  type='text' name='num_refeicao[]' value='" + 
                    holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html() + 
                    "' ><input type='text' name='num_bebida[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>"
                );
            }
        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

e o de recuperar e mostrar em tela

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}



         $sql= "SELECT id_pedido,numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida,data FROM mpedido";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

?>

    <html>
    <h1>Peixaria</h1>
    <ul class="menu cf">
      <li><a href="secao.php">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="pedidos.php">Pedidos</a></li>
      <li><a href="reserva.php">Reserva</a></li>
      <li><a href="relatorio.php">Relatório</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="f-accordion">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Pedidos</h3>
  <div>



    <aside class="alert success">
  <p><i class="icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Roger Roger, Message Received. <i class="close fa fa-times"></i></p>
</aside><!-- end alert -->

<!---
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
---->
<input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" placeholder="Filtrer" /> <a class="button"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Report Error</a>
    <section class="table-box">
        <table class="order-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Comanda</th>
                    <th>N°Mesa</th>
                    <th>Refeição</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Bebida</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["id_pedido"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["numero_mesa"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["pedido_refeicao"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["num_refeicao"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["pedido_bebida"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["num_bebida"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["data"].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';

            }
                ?>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

e a estrutura do bd

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara, entre neste chat pra eu tentar te ajudar por favor, tem várias coisas que talvez precise mudar aí https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133673/ajudar-allan-araujo

Comment: lá ta dizendo que preciso 20 de reputação .

Comment: Puts... cara, me manda e-mail em edsonhoraciojunior@gmail.com que é melhor, se não essa pergunta vai virar um chat

Comment: já enviei uma mensagem

Comment: sim. só que ele está colocando a refeicao e bebida na mesma tabela , e  está inserindo mais uma refeicao e  bebida no lugar correto e a quantidades tudo no mesmo lugar também .

Comment: sim eu uso . está quase tudo correto , só na forma de como é enviada para o bd , tipo a refeicão e bebida estão indo pra coluna de quantidades da refeicao, e a quantidades estão ficando juntas na colunas da quantidades de bebidas e  ainda aparece mais um pedido de bebida e refeição no lugar correto .

Comment: o erro está do javascript e não no banco de dados

Comment: já falei tudo que poderia falar e você não me deu nenhuma solução .

Comment: @LocalHost como eu poderia resolver isso ?

Comment: Tem como você mostrar como tá salvando os dados no banco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

Não sei se entendi bem o problema, a tua dúvida não está clara, seria interessante que você explicasse melhor.

No entanto, olhando teu javascript, percebi que você está fazendo append de um input disabled.

Por padrão, o conteúdo de um input disabled, não é enviado quando você faz um submit no formulário.

Se a intenção é não permitir a alteração manual por parte do usuário, você pode deixar esse input como readonly, ou seja, apenas leitura.

```
<input type="text" name="exemplo" value="Texto" readonly>
```

Dessa forma, quando o formulário for enviado, o conteúdo do campo "exemplo", estará no array $_POST.

Comment: da forma que está agora quando eu faço o pedido ele dar o seguinte erro Notice: Undefined index: num_refeicao in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\pedidos.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: num_bebida in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\pedidos.php on line 17

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\pedidos.php on line 18

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\pedidos.php on line 18 e no banco de dado só aparece o id e o numero da mesa , um array no campo de refeição e outra na bebida , na quantidade fica em branco.

Comment: Se você puder mostrar teu código atual em algum lugar como o https://jsfiddle.net/ ajudaria bastante.

Comment: no momento ela está assim https://jsfiddle.net/milordzin/kks9rads/ , na minha concepção e. tipo o código javascript é para aparece o que foi selecionado no select e mostrar o campo de input quantidade , mas tipo ele tá adicionando o pedido da refeição e bebidas e quantidades nas mesma colunas sendo que cada um tem sua coluna no banco de dados como mostra a imagem acima , poderia me ajudar

Comment: To dando uma olhada no teu fiddle. Até aqui tudo bem.
O erro que você está apontando no comentário acima se refere ao preenchimento do $_POST. Quando você dá um var_dump($_POST), qual é o resultado?

Answer (score -3):

Não é possível a não ser que você esteja usando nodejs no servidor com o módulo do mysql para nodejs.
Caso contrário será necessário um webservice em PHP ou qualquer outra linguagem de servidor.
Assim você envia os dados para esse webservice e ele cuida de registrar no Mysql

Comment: Dá para fazer uma requisição ajax ou usar JS para popular um `input` de um `form` para ser enviado para o backend.
Essa deve ser a 3ª ou 4ª pergunta que o rapaz faz aqui no SO, ele está com dificuldades nessa tela faz um tempo, a pergunta dele é mais simples que tu imagina.